# Konica Minolta C368 printer, can't save with Account Track details

Tags: printing

An office I manage has a Konica Minolta printer with account tracking enabled. In Windows I can save the password assigned in the printer settings, but this option does not seem to be available on Mac OS Ventura.

When I go to print, enter printer options, output method and check on account track, I get the expected dialog to enter the department name and password, but I can't save the settings:

[image]

When I click between department and password fields, the "save settings" checkbox briefly flashes active, then immediately deactivates again. As described on [this page](https://assist.plus.konicaminolta.asia/content/how-key-user-authenticationaccount-track-printer-driver-mac-os), the save settings checkbox should be active, but isn't. Mac OS Ventura looks a bit different than what's shown in the guide, but the expected pages/information is all still there, and we did install the Ventura drivers from the Konica site.

Printing succeeds if we go through the process of entering this account track password, but fails otherwise. Any ideas why I can't save these settings like I can on Windows?